# LetsEncrypt - force X4 root in chain before it becomes default

Tags: lets-encrypt

As part of working on a brand new API, we use LetsEncrypt for generating ssl certificates.

LetsEncrypts current root CA (the "...X3"-version expires at september 2021). They originally planned on making the X4 the default as of september 29 2021 (yesterday).

But it turns out, they prolonged the change until Janurary 11st due to lack of propagation on some devices. Source: https://letsencrypt.org/2019/04/15/transitioning-to-isrg-root.html

I struggle to find out if it is possible for me to force my LetsEncrypt to use the new X4-root CA. This way, our new customers on the new API will be faced with potential ceritificate issues upfront (if they dont have the x4 root certificate) instead of having an issue later when we choose to renew the cerificate to the X4.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible or point me at a direction of such information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the same post at the LetsEncrypt forum. Link: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/force-x4-root-in-chain-before-it-becomes-default/134893